# Find P if Integrating factor of $x(1-x^2)dy+(2x^2y-y-ax^3)dx=0$ is $e^{\int Pdx}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, partial-functions

I have seen one method which correctly evaluates $P=\frac{2x^2-1}{x(1-x^2)}$.

But I have seen a method that says if $\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{N}$ is a function of just x ,i.e, it is equal to f(x) then its

Integrating Factor (IF)=$e^{\int f(x)dx}$

Here M=$2x^2y-y-ax^3$ and N=$x(1-x^2)$

So, $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=2x^2-1$ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=1-3x^2$

Hence, $$\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{N}=\;\;\frac{5x^2-2}{x(1-x^2)}$$

Here's the link to the first method: https://haygot.s3.amazonaws.com/questions/1374381_1134731_ans_55dd44fc75824f228cd5c8286c3144f1.jpg

**Please tell why the answer is not matching.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrating factor need not to be unique for the non-exact equation $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$. The integrating factor $\mu(x)$ obtained by the method you used may lead to a solution which misses some solution of given ODE or conatin an extra solution (*kind of weed*) which is not the solution of given ODE.  Though in this case, the final solution will be same irrespective of the different $\mu(x)$ obtained in the two methods as it is free from variable $y$.

Comment: So how we know when to use which method? Because in certain cases the method I used correctly gives the IF.

Comment: You can certainly use this method but with the caution of loosing or gaining (extra) solution; for which you need to verify at end.

Comment: Pls tell what you mean by verifying at the end and how do i do it. I am a beginner idk much

Comment: Consider $ydx-xdy=0$ with $\mu(y)=1/y^2; y\ne 0$ as integrating factor. On multiplication of it with ODE and solving you get $x/y=c$ as solution which doesn't include $y(x)=0$ (the lost solution). You can verify at the end that $y(x)=0$ is indeed the solution of original ODE.